# Paragraph 2 column layout

Tags: css, drupal, twig

Below is my paragraph.html.twig template:

```
{% block paragraph %}
    <div{{attributes.addClass(classes)}}>
        <div{{content_wrapper_attributes}}>
            {% block content %}
                {{ content }}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock paragraph %}
```

I am trying to display fields in 2 columns as below:

```
fieldtitle1  value
fieldtitle2  value
fieldtitle3  value
.....        ....
```

right now the above template prints everything row-by-row:

```
fieldtitle1  
value
fieldtitle2  
value
fieldtitle3  
value
.....        
....
```

Can someone pls guide me on how to convert this template?

Answer (score -1):

First of all I recommend [activate twig debugging](https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/debugging-twig-templates) for an easier templates discovery and debugging.

You are in the right `paragraph.html.twig` template.

You can print the `{{ dump(content|keys) }}` variable and see that all your fields are available there.

Field title should work with `content.your_field_name.fieldDefinition.label`

Field value should be accessible with `content.your_field_name.value`.